# Mapping the heroku cedar model to a multithreaded application

Tags: java, spring, heroku, concurrency

I'm not really understanding the dyno and worker process model of Heroku as it relates to a single process but multi-threaded Java-based server.

For example: How do I know (for a single dyno) how many processors are available for my background threads? Do I need to use something like RabbitMQ and create a separate process (app) for each background processing task and communicate between the server and these? Seems a little overkill for some Scheduled Tasks using Thread Cached Executors. Should all Futures be changed to inter-process Futures?

I guess it comes down to this question. Can I no longer write a multi-threaded server and scale the processors available to my server process in order to accommodate my thread activity? Or do I need to refactor my architecture to use separate processes for concurrency? If the former, do I need workers or just multiple dynos?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Heroku supports multiple concurrency models, so it's really up to you how you would like to architect your application. You have access to the full Java stack, so if something makes more sense to just be run as multiple threads in your web processes, you can definitely do that, or you can always enqueue jobs on something like RabbitMQ or Redis and process them on separate worker dynos. Multithreading is simpler and makes sense if the amount of work is light and proportional to your web requests because it will be scaled along with the web dynos; however, if the work is large, not proportional, and/or needs to be scaled independently, then breaking it out into a separate process would be better.

Heroku was originally just a Ruby platform, which does not have the same threading capabilities as Java, so the use of separate worker dynos is more important for Ruby and this is reflected in some of the documentation and examples out there, which might have led to your confusion. Luckily, with Java you have more options available to you and can use what's best for the job at hand.

Comment: Thanks! I'm having a difficult time looking for how to configure these threading models. Can you point me to a document?

Comment: There's nothing Heroku-specific here, so any tutorial on Java concurrency would work. Here is a good place to start: http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaConcurrency/article.html. It goes through the whole gamut including low level threads and locks that you'll probably want to avoid in practice in favor of newer abstractions in the `java.util.concurrent` package,  but good to still understand them because they are underlying the whole system. If you want even higher-level abstractions with actors, take a look at [Akka](http://akka.io/).

Comment: ...and if you do want to see how the Heroku-specific multi-dyno web/worker approach works with Java on Heroku, take a look at https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/asynchronous-web-worker-model-using-rabbitmq-in-java

Comment: That's not really what I mean. I'm well acquainted with threading in Java and other languages. However, I don't know how to allocate Heroku resources so that they will have the right CPU's, etc. for a *single* Process. All I see is that there is one DYNO per Process and that they can be 512M or 1G in memory size. But what about concurrency for that dyno? The article you linked is simply using multiple processes for concurrency (interprocess communication), but I'm looking for configuring Heroku for intra-process concurrency.

Comment: There's nothing really to configure on Heroku for intra-process concurrency since it just works out of the box just like any other Java application. Just create a thread pool and start throwing jobs at it. Here is an simple [example of a multithreaded app running on Heroku](http://java-concurrency-example.herokuapp.com/) and here is the [source code](https://github.com/ryanbrainard/java-concurrency-example). As far as CPU allocation, that is not something you can control outside of choose a 1X or 2X dyno.

Comment: Sorry if I'm not being clear. How you configure and write multi-threaded code varies based on the number of cores a server has. For example, you might have a thread pool with 8 threads processing a queue if your server has 4 cores. So that value 8 you want to configure differently based on the server. So how many cores does a dyno have? Can I add more?

Comment: A dyno does not have a set number of CPUs, but you can use `Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors()` to find out at runtime. Dynos are virtualized containers so you will have a share of the full processing power of the entire machine, and this share can be doubled with a [2X dyno](https://blog.heroku.com/archives/2013/4/5/2x-dynos-beta). To get a better idea of how much CPU your dyno is using, check out [log-runtime-metrics](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/log-runtime-metrics).